# How to browse items with extended information?

Tags: filter, master-details

I am wondering what your thoughts are: When browsing articles in a shop (e.g. Ebay), we first see a list. If we click an item, we get the details page of that item, losing all context from the previous articles list.

Would it make sense to "open/close" the article details in a list? So, having an extended article view in the list, and a basic if it is not selected? How would a trigger be used for the selection? (mouse click on the item? elsewhere?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, there is a link "back to the list" doing what you say - depending on whether user came from a category or from search results, leading to that place.

However, there is another pattern I find useful for that (and it can be used not only in e-shops), where having switched to the entry view, user is still presented a short list of entries that are close on the list. It looks like this:

[image]

Using this kind of pattern, you will let user:

- see the **article details without losing context**
- switch **directly to the next entries** on the list
- easily navigate **back to the full list** (category or search results)

Comment: thank you! that is very nice! By the way, my demo case is here: http://palmedor.herokuapp.com - it is in the context of a JavaScript that I am writing.

Comment: Your answer resulted into the following mock.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dominik answer, I arrive at this browser layout.

[image: master/details]